# Boto gets availablity zone wrong when creating a volume on ec2 with spot instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

How is this possible with boto?

```
<Response><Errors><Error><Code>InvalidVolume.ZoneMismatch</Code><Message>The volume 'vol-6c954e27' is not in the same availability zone as instance 'i-3c7d1113'</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>8332fa44-3ca5-4a4e-aef4-ce928c258a03</RequestID></Response>
```

1) I make a spot request:

```
req = conn_spot.request_spot_instances(price=self.spot_price,instance_type=self.instance_type, ebs_optimized=self.ebs_optimized,                                         image_id=self.ami,availability_zone_group=self.zone,key_name=self.keypair,security_groups=[self.security_group])
```

2) I attached a volume:

```
region_id = boto.ec2.get_region(self.region_id, aws_access_key_id=self.aws_access_key_id,
                                 aws_secret_access_key=self.aws_secret_access_key)
conn = ec2.connection.EC2Connection(region=region_id, aws_access_key_id=self.aws_access_key_id,
                                        aws_secret_access_key=self.aws_secret_access_key)
conn.create_volume(self.volume, self.zone,volume_type=self.volume_type,iops=self.iops)
```

zone was set by self.zone which is the same for both which is us-east-1a but the server was created in us-east-1e while the volume is us-east-1a  What did I miss?

Did the spot request ignore my required zone?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with boto (I prefer to use the REST API directly) but it sounds like, from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-pricing-interruptions.html#spot-az-provision that you'd be better off specifying the *subnet* rather than the "availability zone group" if you want to control where your instance will be launched, in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

From [RequestSpotInstances documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_RequestSpotInstances.html):

> **AvailabilityZoneGroup**
>
> The user-specified name for a logical grouping of bids.
>
> When you specify an Availability Zone group in a Spot Instance request, all Spot Instances in the request are launched in the same Availability Zone. Instance proximity is maintained with this parameter, but the choice of Availability Zone is not. The group applies only to bids for Spot Instances of the same instance type. Any additional Spot Instance requests that are specified with the same Availability Zone group name are launched in that same Availability Zone, as long as at least one instance from the group is still active.

So, this field does not actually specify a particular Availability Zone. Rather, it is a user-specified name used to keep instances grouped together in the same Availability Zone.

The `placement` field is used to specify the Availability Zone, but I suspect this is only for use under EC2-Classic.

**When running under VPC you should actually specify a `subnet_id`**, since each subnet resides within a single Availability Zone.

It would also be advisable to extract the Availability Zone from the details of the launched instance using `get_only_instances()`, and then use that value for the `create_volume()` call. This will guarantee a matching Availability Zone.